# Caching table at startup ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I have ASP.NET MVC application, where I keep all of drop down values in a table. So on average every page accesses this table 2-3 times. I want to cache (load into memory) this table on application startup.

Is there a way to do so? I have googled, but helpful topics found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [built-in cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx). As far as the application startup is concerned you could use the `Application_Start` method in `global.asax`.

Answer (score 0):

Would loading it into a static variable do it for you?

You could populate it via the static constructor of whatever class your variable was contained in.

Sidenote: Have you tried just populating the drop down values dynamically on each page load?  Was curious if this was a case of pre-optimizing that might not be necessary.

Comment: I'm currently dynamically populating drop down list, but since the table is huge and this table is accessed almost in every page I decided to optimize it. Static variable is/may be a solution, but I was wondering is there any built-in/other mechanism that handle this caching.